# Sum the series to n terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

$S=x+x^2+x^4+x^8+x^{16}\dots\dots$ to n terms

I tried to think a lot in this question, but didn't get anything useful.

Problem here is that powers itself are in G.P and it is making it difficult to tackle this question.

Comment: @user3290550, what is the source of this problem?

Comment: @PeterForeman It isn't really a duplicate, because no one came up with a simple form for the sum. Or put differently the function has not (yet) been given a widely accepted name.